# Streaming data to axios Javascript frontend from Flask python backend

Tags: javascript, python, flask, backend

I am trying to send multiple packets of data back from my backend to my frontend. I don't know how I could get more data returned then only one 'packet' I have tried looking into socketIO but this hasn't helped me so far. I have also tried using axios for the same results with no succes.

this is what I have as a function in my frontend:

```js
    functionExample() {
        var bodyFormData = new FormData();

        bodyFormData.append('test', 'test');

        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://ip:port/',
            data: bodyFormData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        })
            .then(function (r) {console.log(r.data);});
    }
```

The Flask backend wait's untill the full body is ran before returning something, thus calling the '.then' method.

What I want to do is recieving multiple packets of data for the progress that the backend has made for ex.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_spotify_info():
    await method1()
    'return function 1 done'
    await method2()
    'return function 2 done'
    'return done'
```

I have no idea what this process is actually called, I have seen things about 'piping' or 'streaming' but I am not sure if this is the thing I am looking for.

Comment: First of all, there is no `await` keyword in Flask, that's only for asyncio. There are several ways to send data from backend to frontend, actually too many. polling, streaming, server-side events, websocket, Socket.IO all come to mind. You probably need to do some reading on these and decide which one is appropriate for the problem you are trying to solve.